# How to detect Enter in C++?

Tags: c++

I use `cin` to input some numbers into my program. Here is the input format:

```
1' '2' '3' '4' '5' ''\n'    //One item includes one number and one space. There is an Enter at the end of input.
```

I need to input these number one by one into an array until there is an Enter.
But the `cin` cannot detect the `'\n'`. Does anyone have good idea for that?

Comment: `std::getline()`? (BTW, `cin` is an object. It doesn't "detect" anything by itself.)

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant std::getline() treats the input as a string, not a set of numbers. How to get the numbers in it?

Comment: @Galaxy You can use std::stringstream for that.

Comment: @MrEricSir Awesome! The std::stringstream just solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Re TheParamagneticCroissant's suggestion: `getline` strips the newline, such that a `string` it sets from input a la `echo -n no newline here | ./my_app` will be identical to `echo newline here | ./my_app`, but you can explicitly test `std::cin.eof()` to differentiate the cases.  I doubt if that's really what you want to do though - question's confusing IMHO, as I'm not sure why the `\n` is shown with two preceding and one trailing single-quote: is the 5 character representation `''\n'` expected on `cin`, rather than a single newline character?

Comment: @TonyD Probably a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer-in-commentor has not posted an answer...

I guess you were initially reading with `int x;` ... `cin >> x`.  The `istream::operator>>(int)` function skips leading whitespace, and newlines count as whitespace. So with that approach you could not distinguish `1 2` from `1\n2`.

Instead you need to use a function that preserves newlines at least (if not all whitespace). `std::getline` is a good function for this purpose.  You can then turn the line into a stream by using a `std::stringstream`.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::string line;

    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::istringstream iss(line); 

    for( int x; iss >> x; )
        numbers.emplace_back(x);

    // Output to test that it worked
    for ( int x : numbers )
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wrote my code in the same way just as you posted above.